# jQuery + ie8 'Object doesn't support this property'

Tags: jquery, methods, properties, internet-explorer-8

I'm running into the following error
[image]

On the line where I set my $content variable:

```
var loadResource = function(url, params, callback) {
    WHOAT.networking.getToServerWithAjax(url, params, function (response) {
        //var $content = $($.parseHTML(response.trim()));
        var $content = $(response.trim());
        var $container = $('#dashboard-display');
        var $content_to_hide = $container.children();

        $.when($content_to_hide.fadeOut('fast')).then(function () {
            $content.hide();
            $container.append($content);

            $content.fadeIn('fast', function(){
                $content_to_hide.remove();

                if(callback) {
                    callback();
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Originally I thought it had something to do with parseHTML, so I tried `var $content = $(response.trim());` on the next line, but it's still throwing this error.

The response is basically just HTML to render a widget that this code loads.

Any thoughts on what I may need to do to get this to work in ie8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) in IE8 but jQuery provides [one](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).

Change

```
    var $content = $(response.trim());
```

to

```
    var $content = $($.trim(response));
```

Comment: Also, ideally you want to use the commented out version with $.parseHTML, though you should still trim it.